# Create a pull request in Azure DevOps via CLI with options

Tags: azure, azure-devops, version-control, devops

How can one create a pull request in Azure DevOps via CLI, specifying options for the PR?

F.x. title, description, reviewers, worked item link, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: [az repos pr create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-repos-pr-create)

How to install: [How to install the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)